# Fedex shipping Method Problem?

Tags: magento-1.9

I Don't know the exact reason, why fedex shipping method not appearing on front end after filling

```
"Account ID", "Meter Number", "Key" & "Password".
```

Though i set these field to yes

```
1. Enabled for Checkout = Yes

2. Sandbox Mode = Yes
```

How to solve this issue ? What the exact problem in this ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: is it solve your problem

Comment: yes, this is solve my problem, actually authenticate Key was not corrected.

Comment: I also get testing  "Account ID", "Meter Number", "Key" & "Password" from fedex, right after go to check website, its not working. where you have  i get testing details, how can i test my fedex. Pls let me know is any other things i am going to follow.

Comment: Try to put USA shipping address (pincode: 95125) to check Fedex shipping method in sandbox mode.

Comment: how can i use sandbox mode, i am new could u pls briefly explain

Comment: Login to admin -> Go to System -> configuration -> Shipping method-> click on Fedex & change 'No' to "yes" in sandbox mode field

Comment: hi rathinam, Is this solve your problem ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/56918/discussion-between-rathinam-and-pankaj).

Comment: Hi, please explain how you got it fixed